# Mono Framework on Mac behind proxy - Safari can access google.com, but HttpClient cannot

Tags: c#, mono, http-proxy

So, I am having issues with a Mac (macOS 13.3.1) running Xamarin / Mono Framework.

The system is behind a proxy (no credentials required). The proxy is fixed, configured in the system settings (no autoconfiguration, no automatic detection).

I can open http://www.google.com in the Safari browser.

My code using HttpClient:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
handler.UseProxy = true;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
try {
     await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
}
catch (HttpRequestException hre) {
    // Causes "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No route to host ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host"
}
```

How can I further debug this issue?